# Web signature with X509 certificate + smartcard

Tags: web, x509certificate, smartcard, fortify

I'm trying to add signature functionality to my web app.

The signature must be made with a smartcard. So, after searching in a lot of places I found *webcrypto-socket* (https://peculiarventures.github.io/webcrypto-local/docs/) - Webcrypto socket module implements Crypto interface and uses *Fortify* application for crypto implementation.

Then, I could sign in to my app but the signature that it produces was not a valid PKCS signature, it was returning only the signature hash without the public certificate.

My code is based on this example: https://peculiarventures.github.io/fortify-examples/example5.html

In addition, comments for webcrypto-socket and fortify are welcome!

I'm doing something like this, where providers and certificates are filled as fortify recommends:

```
function sign() {
    var provider;
    var cert;
    Promise.resolve()
        .then(function () {
            var providerID = document.getElementById("providers").value;
            return ws.getCrypto(providerID)
        })
        .then(function (crypto) {
            provider = crypto;
```

> ```
>           setEngine('subtle', crypto,
> ```

```
    new CryptoEngine({ name: 'subtle', crypto: crypto, subtle: crypto.subtle }));

            return GetCertificate(provider,
                document.getElementById("certificates").value);
        })
        .then(function (certificate) {
            cert = certificate;
            return GetCertificateKey("private", provider,
                document.getElementById("certificates").value);
        })
        .then(function (key) {
            if (!key) {
                throw new Error("Certificate doesn't have private key");
            }

            var textToSignElement = document.getElementById("textToSign");
            var signatureResultElement = 
                document.getElementById("signatureResult");
            signDataElement(textToSignElement, signatureResultElement, 
                cert, key, provider);

        })
}

function signDataElement(textToSignElement, signatureResultElement, 
    key, cert, provider) {
    var message = pvtsutils.Convert.FromBase64(hashElement.value);
    var hashAlg = key.algorithm.hash.name;
    var sequence = Promise.resolve();
    sequence = sequence.then(() => provider.subtle.digest({ name: hashAlg },
        new Uint8Array(message)));
    var cmsSignedSimpl = null;
    var messHex = null;
    var certRaw = null;

    sequence = sequence.then(function (res) {
        messHex = res;
        return GetCertificateAsPEM(provider, cert);
    });

    //region Combine all signed extensions
    sequence = sequence.then(result => {
        certRaw = result;
        var signedAttr = [];

        signedAttr.push(new Attribute({
            type: "1.2.840.113549.1.9.3",
            values: [new ObjectIdentifier({ value: "1.2.840.113549.1.7.1" })]
        })); // contentType

        signedAttr.push(new Attribute({
            type: "1.2.840.113549.1.9.5",
            values: [new UTCTime({ valueDate: new Date() })]
        })); // signingTime

        signedAttr.push(new Attribute({
            type: "1.2.840.113549.1.9.4",
            values: [new OctetString({ valueHex: messHex})]
        })); // messageDigest

        return signedAttr;
    });

    sequence = sequence.then(signedAttr => {
        var asn1 = fromBER(PemToDer(certRaw));
        var newCert = new Certificate({ schema: asn1.result });

        newCert.issuer.typesAndValues.push(new AttributeTypeAndValue({
            type: "2.5.4.3", // Common name
            value: new BmpString({ value: cert.issuerName })
        }));
        cmsSignedSimpl = new SignedData({
            version: 1,
            encapContentInfo: new EncapsulatedContentInfo({
                eContentType: "1.2.840.113549.1.7.1" // "data" content type
            }),
            signerInfos: [new SignerInfo({
                version: 1,
                sid: new IssuerAndSerialNumber({
                    issuer: newCert.issuer,
                    serialNumber: newCert.serialNumber
                }),
                signedAttrs: new SignedAndUnsignedAttributes({
                    type: 0,
                    attributes: signedAttr
                })
            })],
            certificates: [newCert]
        });
        return cmsSignedSimpl.sign(key, 0, hashAlg, message)
    });

    sequence = sequence.then(() => {
        var cmsSignedSchema = cmsSignedSimpl.toSchema(true);

        var cmsContentSimp = new ContentInfo({
            contentType: "1.2.840.113549.1.7.2",
            content: cmsSignedSchema
        });

        var _cmsSignedSchema = cmsContentSimp.toSchema();

        //region Make length of some elements in "indefinite form"
        _cmsSignedSchema.lenBlock.isIndefiniteForm = true;

        var block1 = _cmsSignedSchema.valueBlock.value[1];
        block1.lenBlock.isIndefiniteForm = true;

        var block2 = block1.valueBlock.value[0];
        block2.lenBlock.isIndefiniteForm = true;

        //endregion

       return _cmsSignedSchema.toBER(false);
    }, error => Promise.reject(`Erorr during signing of CMS Signed Data: ${error}`));

    sequence.then((certificateBuffer) => {
        var certSimplString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, 
            new Uint8Array(certificateBuffer));

        signatureElement.value = formatPEM(window.btoa(certSimplString));

        alert("Certificate created successfully!");
    })

    return sequence;
}

function GetCertificate(provider, certID) {
    var certID;
    return provider.certStorage.getItem(certID)
        .then(function (cert) {
            return cert;
        });
}

function GetCertificateAsPEM(provider, cert) {
    return provider.certStorage.exportCert('PEM', cert);
}
```

The *signDataElement* is based on https://pkijs.org/examples/CMSSigned_complex_example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use Fortify (https://fortifyapp.com) in Hancock (https://hancock.ink) with PKIjs (https://pkijs.org) and CAdESjs (https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/CAdES.js) to create a CMS signature.

You can see a basic CMS example in JS based on PKIjs here: https://pkijs.org/examples/CMSSigned_complex_example.html

You will need to provide us with an example of what you are doing and we can tell you what you need to do differently.

Ryan

Comment: Ryan, thanks for answering.

I added some code i'm using to sign.

I was looking at the example you mentioned and what I could not achieve is to obtain the certificate in base 64 ..

Comment: Nacho, it doesnt seem you have tried using the CMS example linked above at all. Happy to help if you run into trouble but I dont have time to do it for you.

Comment: Ryan, I've read the examples and If i'm not wrong, I need the private and public key or the PEM certificate. I've tried in different ways but i couldn't :(

Comment: You do not need the private key, WebCrypto abstracts that for you. Since you have provided no code attempting to do what your requesting without simply writing the code for you I don’t have much I can do. In your earlier response you asked about how to get the certificate, it’s not clear what your application flow looks like but if you need to enumerate certificates you can see this example: https://peculiarventures.github.io/fortify-examples/example4.html

Comment: Ryan, I've edited the answer and added more code. I hope It's clearer

Comment: It looks like you did not use setEngine in PKIjs to indicate that Fortify is to be used. something like : ```  setEngine('Crypto', crypto, new CryptoEngine({ name: 'Crypto', crypto, subtle: crypto.subtle })); ```

Comment: Ryan, Thanks! You were right! I made the signature correctly, but now i need the signer info XD.
And et looks like the certificate object that Fortify returns does not define a toBER function, how can I import correctly the certificate to a PKI.js Certificate? Or is there another alternative? Thanks

Comment: You can see how to decode a certificate with PKIjs here https://pkijs.org/examples/X509_cert_complex_example.html

Comment: Ryan, I don't understand how to use that example, because it reads the .cer file but I only have the object from Fortify and I couldn't make the schema that asn1 expects in `new Certificate({ schema: ** });`

Comment: Ryan, Thanks I do it with `provider.certStorage.exportCert('PEM', cert);`. Now is signing correctly